# How to perform multiple search using php regex?

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_match("/Designer:(.*?)|Created by:(.*?)\n/i",$sitesource,$designer);
```

Hi, Can anyone tell me how can I perform multiple searches? For example, if the "designer" keyword not found, then search for "created by" and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
preg_match_all("/(?:Created by|Designer):(.*)/i", $sitesource, $designer);
```

That is, use `preg_match_all` to match multiple occurrences and merge the two alternatives into a simpler `(?:Created by|Designer):(.*)` that means

- `(?:Created by|Designer)` - either `Created by` or `Designer`
- `:` - a colon
- `(.*)` - capturing group #1: the rest of the line.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RqLWMY/1).